# there are many send requests expired when I use KafkaConsumer:commitAsync commit offset

Tags: apache-kafka, timeoutexception

I had a  kafka consumer that processes 2w messages per second  and  I used  commitAsync  method  to commit offset with manual commit offset . on this case, I found many offset commit failed logs like `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 60000 ms`,so I  read the source code ,I find the log was produced by  the mehotd of   `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient#failExpiredRequests`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvD6m.png)

I modify the param `max.poll.records=1000`, but this no effect;

Answer (score 0):

Doubling the number of consumed records won't help you to commit any of offsets you've consumed within the timeout window

The error is suggesting that you either 1) **retry** the commit (catch in a loop, and commit again), or 2) *reduce* max.poll.records from default 500 to something smaller, increase your timeouts (although one minute should be more than enough), or commit more frequently